# Tried Linear, SVR for domain name price evaluation, how to predict in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, dns, prediction, domain-name

Any body tried any model in machine learning for domain name price prediction.
I have tried Linear, Polynomial and SVR RBF and result is not satisfied except RBF.
RBF gives repeated same price prediction for different domain.

Convereted domain name into numbers as a=01,b=02.etc...

[image: Preprocessed dataset]

[image: predict]

So what model will be best to predict this and how.

Comment: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Is This On Topic?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Domains are not just characters. Trying to predict their price/value without any external data is kind of impossible.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, looking at your dataset I think that you should delete the "DomainID" column, as it serves no purpose in your task. Regarding the model, you can maybe start simply by using Linear Regression, and if the results are still not good enough for you, try using a "fancier" one, or change the approach a little bit and use a Neural Network.

Comment: If Domain name abc.com it will be converted to 010203027031513 this is domain id.. whether i need to use any scalar like that. What will be the minimum dataset.